# Cannot resolve method 'setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' in 'Builder'

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a register activity to allow a user to register however I keep getting the error:

> Cannot resolve method 'setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' in 'Builder'"

It's only the section which has the `setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled` that is giving me the issue. Do I need an implementation?

Here is my Java code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";

    //widgets
    private EditText mEmail, mPassword, mConfirmPassword;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    //vars
    private FirebaseFirestore mDb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        mConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_confirm_password);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_register).setOnClickListener(this);

        mDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    /**
     * Register a new email and password to Firebase Authentication
     * @param email
     * @param password
     */
    public void registerNewEmail(final String email, String password){

        showDialog();

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: AuthState: " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                            //insert some default data
                            User user = new User();
                            user.setEmail(email);
                            user.setUsername(email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@")));
                            user.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());



                            FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                                    .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                                    .build();
                            mDb.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

                            FirebaseFirestoreSettings newUserRef = mDb
                                    .collection(getString(R.string.collection_users))
                                    .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

                            newUserRef.set(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    hideDialog();

                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        redirectLoginScreen();
                                    }else{
                                        View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                                        Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "Something went wrong.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        else {
                            View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                            Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "Something went wrong.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            hideDialog();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Redirects the user to the login screen
     */
    private void redirectLoginScreen(){
        Log.d(TAG, "redirectLoginScreen: redirecting to login screen.");

        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    private void showDialog(){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    private void hideDialog(){
        if(mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_register:{
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to register.");

                //check for null valued EditText fields
                if(!isEmpty(mEmail.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mPassword.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mConfirmPassword.getText().toString())){

                    //check if passwords match
                    if(doStringsMatch(mPassword.getText().toString(), mConfirmPassword.getText().toString())){

                        //Initiate registration task
                        registerNewEmail(mEmail.getText().toString(), mPassword.getText().toString());
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Passwords do not Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You must fill out all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be unusual for a builder style method to be a setter (start with set). Try .timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at the current [documentation for `FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder), I don't see any `setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled` method. So that probably explains the error message: you're trying to call a method that doesn't exist.

My guess is that your code was meant for an older version of the SDK when the method *did* exist. Since it doesn't exist anymore now, you either have to use the version of the SDK that the code was made for, or remove the call.

**Update**: it looks like [`timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled` was removed in version 22](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v22-0-0) of the Android SDK for Firestore back in October 2020.